# TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float' python 2.7

Tags: python, raw-input

Hi I'm a 11 year old who has taken up python as a hobby. I'm trying to make a mass converter as a first project. But for some reason I've been getting this error: TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Here is my code:

```
    print "please enter the amount of kilograms you want to convert",
    kilo = raw_input() 
    pounds = 2.20462

    print kilo * pounds
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`raw_input` returns a string, you're basically doing this:

```
print "1234" * 2.20462
```

You need to convert the input to a number:

```
kilo = float(raw_input())
pounds = 2.20462

print kilo * pounds
```

The error message is somewhat confusing because you can multiply a string (or any sequence) by an integer:

```
print "abc" * 3   # prints "abcabcabc"
```