# TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float', I can't figure out

Tags: python

This is that piece of code I wrote:

```
#This is the first ever piece of code I/'m Writing here
#This calculates the value after applying GST
#Example: here we are applying on a smartphone costing 10000
Cost = input('Enter the MRP of device here ')

Tax = 0.12
Discount = 0.05

Cost = Cost + Cost * float(Tax)
Total = Cost + Cost * float(Discount)

print(Total)
```

Whenever I try to execute the code it gives an exception after input:

`TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float' python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16268935/typeerror-cant-multiply-sequence-by-non-int-of-type-float-python-2-7)

Comment: short answer: `input` returns a `str` in python3. You have to convert it to a numeric type. You also have calls to `float` around `Tax` and `Discount` but those are already `float`s so they don't do anything for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few weird parts here I'll try to break them down. The first is the one you are actually asking about which is caused by `input` returning a string, so you are effectively doing something like this. I'm going to lowercase the variable names to match [python style](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

```
cost = "2.50"
tax = 0.12
#...
cost * tax # multiplying str and float
```

Fix this by wrapping the call to input with a call to `float` to convert the `str`

```
cost = float(input('Enter the MRP of device here '))
tax = 0.12
discount = 0.5
```

next you have these extra calls `float(tax)` and `float(discount)`. Since both of these are floats already, you don't need this.

There is also a shorthand syntax for `x = x + y` which is `x += y` with these two things in mind, you can adjust your calculation lines:

```
cost += cost * tax
cost += cost * discount
print(cost)
```

Comment: also the code from the question will run in python 2.7 because of the way `input()` works there https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=input#input

Answer (score 1):

raw input is as string,cast it into float

```
Cost = input('Enter the MRP of device here ')
Cost=float(Cost)
Tax = 0.12
Discount = 0.05

Cost = Cost + Cost * float(Tax)
Total = Cost + Cost * float(Discount)

print(Total)
```

Comment: s/cast/convert. Why did you leave the extra `float` calls in? Why not wrap the call to `input` instead of having it in two lines?

Comment: i wanted to make it clear for him,trying to understand where he was stuck

Comment: @AbhinavTomar, please accept the answer by clicking the V button below the vote